# How to plot profiles in front of a 2D field in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following script that plots me a 2D field of some quantity in the domain:

```
def field(x, y, z):

    fig, (ax) = plt.subplots()
    ax.tricontour(x, y, z)
    cntr = ax.tricontourf(x, y, z)
    fig.colorbar(cntr, ax=ax)
    plt.show()
```

Which gives me something like:

[image]

I want to add profiles on top of that figure, i.e.:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) on `ax`, setting `linewidth` (short `lw`) and `color` (short `c`) as needed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.uniform(-5, 40, 50)
y = np.random.uniform(-.25, .25, 50)
z = y * 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,2))
cntr = ax.tricontourf(x, y, z)
fig.colorbar(cntr, ax=ax)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 35), ylim=(-.2, .2))

for i in range(5, 35, 5):
    ax.plot([i-1, i+1], [0.2, -0.2], lw=5, c='k')
```

[image]